# Как объединить строки, полученные из цикла?

Tags: java

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExample {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "username";
   static final String PASS = "password";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   PreparedStatement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      String sql = "UPDATE Employees set age=? WHERE id=?";
      stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

      //Bind values into the parameters.
      stmt.setInt(1, 35);  // This would set age
      stmt.setInt(2, 102); // This would set ID

      // Let us update age of the record with ID = 102;
      int rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
      System.out.println("Rows impacted : " + rows );

      // Let us select all the records and display them.
      sql = "SELECT id, age FROM Employees";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
      while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name
         int a  = rs.getInt("id");
         int b = rs.getInt("age");

         //Display values
         System.out.print("ID: " + a);
         System.out.print(", Age: " + b);

      }
      //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end JDBCExample
```

Всего две переменные, в которые собираются данные. На выходе из массива получаю следующие значения:

```
a = 1 
b = 1,2,3,

a = 1
b = 4,5,6,

a = 1 
b = 7,8,9,

a = 10 
b = 10,20,30,

a = 10 
b = 40,50,60,
```

**Как объединить b, при условии если наши a - совпадают?  Чтобы получилось:**

```
a = 1 
b = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,

a = 10 
b = 10,20,30,40,50,60,
```

p.s. если нужен исходный код цикла, который я использую: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/preparestatement-object-example.htm

Comment: Все-таки лучше добавить в вопрос код цикла (код по ссылке не проясняет ситуацию нет там ни `a` ни `b`) и указать точно какой тип у `a` и `b`

Comment: добавил полный код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понял почему в примере на каждое a приходится несколько b. Судя по коду на каждой итерации обрабатывается одно значение `a` и одно значение `b`.

Для того чтобы сохранить для каждого a множество уникальных значений b можно использовать [отображение](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>` в котором ключом является `a`, а значением — [множество](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) `b`.

Объявить его можно так:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> agesById = new HashMap<>();
```

Затем можно добавлять элементы:

```
//получаем множество, соответствующее a
Set<Integer> ages = agesById.get(a);
//если a еще не добавлено в отображение
if(ages==null) {
    //создаем пустое множество 
    ages = new HashSet<>();
    //и присваиваем его как значение по a
    agesById.put(a, ages);
}
//добавляем b в множество
ages.add(b);
```

После этого можно перебрать список всех значений `a` (`id`) и соответствующих им `b` (`age`):

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> entry : agesById.entrySet()) {
    int id = entry.getKey();
    Set<Integer> ages = entry.getValue();
    //что-то с ними делаем
    System.out.println(id+": "+ages);
}
```

Если нужно, чтобы значение возраста, которое встречается по заданному id два раза в результате дублировалось — используйте List вместо Set.